# Intel GPU not detected by games on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, broadcom, gpu

My brother installed ubuntu on an old iMac14 before moving away and giving me the PC. I loved ubuntu until recently when I udpated to 22.04 and it stopped recognising my GPU and crashing any game I open with the error message "No GPU found". I have tried switching to an NVIDIA driver but I can't get it to show up under my additional drivers which is a step all the guides require. All I have under additional drivers is Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver. I've also tried updating Ubuntu to 23.04 but whenever I click Upgrade in the software updater the window closes and nothing happens. I've looked at every GPU not detected thread on the planet and nothing has worked, I seem to keep running into this error with intel-i915-dkms that I cant resolve. I'm very new to linux and I don't know what to include here to help but any help you can offer is very appreciated!

```
justin@name:~$ inxi -Fxxzc0
System:
  Kernel: 6.2.0-34-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME 42.9
    tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Apple product: iMac14,1 v: 1.0
    serial: <superuser required> Chassis: type: 13 v: Mac-031B6874CF7F642A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Apple model: Mac-031B6874CF7F642A v: iMac14,1
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Apple v: 146.0.0.0.0 date: 06/10/2020
Battery:
  Device-1: hid-68:d9:3c:e7:cc:53-battery model: N/A serial: N/A charge: N/A
    status: Discharging
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Core i5-4570R bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Haswell
    rev: 1 cache: L1: 256 KiB L2: 1024 KiB L3: 4 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 798 high: 800 min/max: 800/3200 cores: 1: 800 2: 798
    3: 798 4: 798 bogomips: 21550
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Apple driver: i915 v: kernel ports: active: DP-3
    empty: DP-1, DP-2, HDMI-A-1, HDMI-A-2, VGA-1 bus-ID: 00:02.0
    chip-ID: 8086:0d22
  Device-2: Apple FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 1-7:2 chip-ID: 05ac:8511
  Display: wayland server: X.org v: 1.21.1.4 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
    gpu: i915 display-ID: 0
  Monitor-1: DP-3 model: Apple iMac res: 1920x1080 dpi: 103
    diag: 545mm (21.5")
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Iris Pro Graphics 5200 (HSW GT3)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.0-devel (git-313c40973b) direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Crystal Well HD Audio vendor: Apple driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 00:03.0 chip-ID: 8086:0d0c
  Device-2: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 chip-ID: 8086:8c20
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.2.0-34-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Broadcom BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Apple
    driver: wl v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 02:00.0
    chip-ID: 14e4:43a0
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Broadcom NetXtreme BCM57766 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe driver: tg3
    v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: N/A bus-ID: 03:00.0
    chip-ID: 14e4:1686
  IF: enp3s0f0 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Apple Bluetooth USB Host Controller type: USB driver: btusb
    v: 0.8 bus-ID: 1-8.3:6 chip-ID: 05ac:828d
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 2.1 lmp-v: 4.0 sub-v: 4190
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 106.4 GiB (11.4%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Apple model: HDD HTS541010A9E662 size: 931.51 GiB
    speed: 3.0 Gb/s serial: <filter>
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 915.32 GiB used: 106.39 GiB (11.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 75.4 MiB (3.7%) priority: -2
    file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 43.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 310 Uptime: 9h 19m Memory: 7.69 GiB used: 5.11 GiB (66.4%)
  Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.4.0 alt: 11/12
  Packages: 2409 apt: 2389 snap: 20 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.16
  running-in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.3.13
```

Comment: Please attach more system info: `sudo apt install inxi` and then `inxi -Fxxzc0` in terminal

Comment: I edited above with system info